# Can't generate build after implementing facebook sdk due to paytm allinOne sdk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, payment-gateway, facebook-sdk-4.0, paytm

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" />
```

This is my android sdk minimum version I installed both facebook and paytm sdk in my app. While generating the build, I'm getting error code 1.

[This is the error I'm getting while generating build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pe1i.png)

If I generate build with faceboook sdk alone, i can generate the build.if both facebook and allinone paytm sdk exist, error occurs. Is there any way to generate build without removing allinOne sdk??

Comment: looks like your question description formatting was off, please try to edit more details, here might helps: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Where do you set `android:minSdkVersion`? Can you show `config.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the minSdkVersion in app/build.gradle

```
   android {
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.merchantapp"
            minSdkVersion 18
            compileSdkVersion 30
            targetSdkVersion 30
            buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
        }

}
```

The one mentioned by you is not the correct way